# Error starting the service. The OracleMTSRecoveryService was not found

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting this error while installing oracle 11g enterprise edition on windows 7 professional 64 bit. I checked the registry as some people have mention but the correct thing is already there. If try starting the service from Services.msc it says the service wss not found also

Comment: Excellent in my case path was defined as C:\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1 and installer was looking for the path C:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this same issue and this solved it:

When you get the error pop-up, leave it opened, open regedit and modify the ImagePath in the following key to point to the proper location:

`computer\hkey_local_machine\system\controlset001\service\OracleMTSRecoveryService`

The proper location may be something like this:

`C:\app\myaccount\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\omtsreco.exe`

All credit to:
http://yuanmengblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/oracle-standard-db-install-issue-with.html

Comment: It would be appreciate if You can sum it up what happened instead of just providing link (which might became unactual).

Answer (score 3):

The oracle download was split into two parts.
If you tried to install with only one part it will show many bugs and after installation oracle won't work.
Download two parts of oracle from the official site and extract in same place. The files will merge automatically into the same folder.

Now install the oracle. If you already installed the oracle once. It should taken some path like below.

In my system it took "**E:\app\INDP\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1...**"

If you are installing second time installation will take path, "**E:\app\INDP\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2...**"

Now the above erorr will come because of registry.
So, now yo need to edit the registry value like below.

- ctrl+R will bring the run window. Type regedit and press ok
- Then Under Computer, select *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM ->ControlSet001-> Services -> OracleMTSRecoveryService*.
- Double click on ImagePath. It will prompt a window with old path or with wrong path under value data.
- Now, you need to edit it with your curent path like below.
- **E:\app\INDP\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\omtsreco.exe OracleMTSRecoveryService**

Now press "retry" button of the window, which shown that error. Now, it will work like charm.